# Entity Framework Code First custom mapping using partial key

Tags: entity-framework-4, frameworks, ef-code-first, entity

Is it possible to do the following mapping with the Entity Framework Code First?

```
public class Parent
{
     [Key]
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string statecode{get; set;}

     public virtual ICollection<Child> children{get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string StateFromCode { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string StateToCode { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to specify a relation in my dbcontext where children are lazy loaded into the Parent and Parent.statecode == Child.StateToCode. Note that StateToCode is part of the Child key and not the entire primary key. What should I specify in my DB context below to make this happen if possible at all?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(x=>x.children)..............

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible - especially not with code first where relations must follow exactly same rules as specifying referential constraint in the database. So the only valid relation will require `Parent`'s Id column in `Child` table and foreign constraint on this column

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I ended up populating children collection manually as 'p.children = dbcontext.Children.where(c=>c.StateToCode == p.statecode)' and changed the collection from ICollection<child> to [NotMapped] IEnumerable<child>.

Comment: Is this still the case, or has the newer version made this functionality available?